# azure sql db Cannot bulk load because the file ".xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null)

Tags: azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert xml file data into Azure SQL DB using stored procedure in github action. But getting error.
**Cannot bulk load because the file ".xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).**

Let me know what can i do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Verify if you have the file in place and appropriate permissions. Can you share the stored procedure you are using ? Some screenshots would help too.

Answer (score 1):

BULK INSERT into Azure SQL DB can only work from Azure Storage Blob, but not from file systems on your local drive.

Here is the same error when I try from local source:
[image]

Refer: [Using BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#using-bulk-insert) , an example showing how to use the BULK INSERT command to load data from a xml file in an Azure Blob storage location on which you have created a SAS key. The Azure Blob storage location is configured as an external data source. This requires a database scoped credential using a shared access signature that is encrypted using a master key in the user database.

Step1:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://myazureblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net', CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential);
```

Step2: Place your file in blob container and access it like below

```
BULK INSERT Product
FROM 'product.csv'WITH (  DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
        FORMAT='CSV', CODEPAGE = 65001, --UTF-8 encoding
        FIRSTROW=2,
        TABLOCK);
```

Refer: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage/LoadFromAzureBlobStorage.sql

Comment: Facing the same issue. However, the official docs do say it is possible to load data from disk: `BULK INSERT can import data from a disk or Azure Blob storage (including network, floppy disk, hard disk, and so on).` More: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Now this is added to the documentation:
"Azure SQL Database only supports reading from Azure Blob Storage."

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get rid of the same issue but the **Import Flat File Wizard** has proven to be an amazing workaround as you can simply import a plain csv|txt file directly into your database.

> First, create a table in your database into which you will import the CSV file. After the table is created:
> Log in to your database using SQL Server Management Studio.

- Right-click the database and select **Tasks** -> **Import Data**...
- Click the **Next >** button.
- For Data Source, select **Flat File Source**. Then use the Browse button to select the CSV file.  Spend some time configuring the data import before clicking the **Next >** button.
- For Destination, select the correct database provider (e.g. for SQL Server 2012, you can use SQL Server Native Client 11.0).  Enter the Server name; check Use SQL Server Authentication, enter the User name, Password, and Database before clicking the **Next >** button.
- In the Select Source Tables and Views window, you can Edit Mappings before clicking the **Next >** button.
- Check Run immediately and click the **Next >** button.
- Click the Finish button to run the package.

---

- [How to import a CSV file into a database using SQL Server Management Studio](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx)
- [Import Flat File to SQL Wizard](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-flat-file-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15#started)